# Find probability that last digit is $0$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 4 whole numbers taken at random are multiplied together, then find the probability that:

$(1)$ Find the probability that the last digit in the product is $5$.

$(2)$ Find the probability that last digit in the product is $0$.

For first part I found probability that last digit is $1,3,5,7$ or $9$ and then then subtracted the probability that last digit is $1,3,7$ or $9$ but how to proceed in second part? There can be many ways to get $0$. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You cannot just say "random integers" without specifying a distribution. Of course, not all number can have the same probability of being selected, as there are infinitely many integers. The answer will depend on the distribution you choose.

Answer (score 2):

For part (1) the answer, as the OP found, is

$$\left(5\over10\right)^4-\left(4\over10\right)^4={625-256\over10000}={369\over10000}=3.69\%$$

(Note, we could have reduced the fractions $5/10$ and $4/10$ to $1/2$ and $2/5$, respectively, but it's more convenient here not to.)

For part (2), the easiest approach is to first calculate the probability that the product ends in *neither* a $0$ *nor* a $5$.  One can then get the desired probability (of ending in a $0$) by noting that the probabilities of the three mutually exclusive events -- end in a $0$, end in a $5$, or end in neither -- must sum to $1$.

A little thought says that the product avoids both $0$ and $5$ if and only if all four numbers do the same.  (Obviously if any of the numbers ends in a $0$, so will the product, while if any of them ends in a $5$, the product will end in a $0$ if any of the others is even, and in a $5$ if the others are all odd.). Hence the probability of ending in neither $0$ nor $5$ is

$$\left(8\over10\right)^4={4096\over10000}$$

Putting this together with the result of part (1), we see that the probability of ending in a $0$ is

$$1-\left({369\over10000}+{4096\over10000}\right)=1-{4465\over10000}={5535\over10000}={1107\over2000}=55.35\%$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Consider the last digit of any $2$ random numbers, and their associated probabilities, and then regard the $4$ numbers as two pairs of $2$ numbers.

Just looking at the basic multiplication table, you find that for $2$ numbers the probabilities for the last digit are:

$1$: $\frac{4}{100}$

$2$: $\frac{12}{100}$

$3$: $\frac{4}{100}$

$4$: $\frac{12}{100}$

$5$: $\frac{9}{100}$

$6$: $\frac{12}{100}$

$7$: $\frac{4}{100}$

$8$: $\frac{12}{100}$

$9$: $\frac{4}{100}$

$0$: $\frac{27}{100}$

To get a 5 as the last digit for $4$ numbers, you need a $5$ and an odd number for the two pairs, so:

$1$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{4}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$ (the $2$ is because the two pairs can switch places)

$3$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{4}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$7$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{4}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$9$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{4}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$5$ + $5$: $\frac{9}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

To get a $0$ as the last digit for $4$ numbers, you either need a $5$ and an even number for the two pairs, or a $0$ and any other number, so:

$2$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{12}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$4$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{12}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$6$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{12}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$8$ + $5$: $2 \cdot \frac{12}{100} \cdot \frac{9}{100}$

$0$ + any number other than $0$: $2 \cdot \frac{27}{100} \cdot \frac{73}{100}$

$0$ + $0$: $\frac{27}{100} \cdot \frac{27}{100}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the questions are equivalent to:

(1) what is the probability of it resulting in an odd multiple of 5?

(2) what is the probability of it resulting in an even multiple of 5?

Comment: For 2):  four numbers that end in a $0$ will work as well.

Comment: @bram28 and all of them will be even multiples of 5 ...

Comment: Sure ... but the hint is a bit misleading, as it suggest you'd need to have a 5 and some even number.  For 1) it works: you really need a $5$ in there, but not for 2)

Comment: @Bram28 it's not if the OP knows anything about the 5 times tables. in fact if they do they don't even need the hint.

Comment: also 5 needs be a factor in one of your random numbers so I don't see how that's misleading I never said ( nor does the question) that the numbers couldn't be composites. and that applies to both questions.